# swift dictionaries: map within a map

Tags: swift, dictionary, enums

I'd like to convert a value I get from an API to a specific format.

```
[String:Any] // format received
[Int:[ContentType:Int]] // required format
```

ContentType is an Enum

An example of the data might look like this:

```
["123":["Tables":"25","Chairs":"14"]] // input
[123:[.Tables:25,.Chairs:14]] // output
```

I think I need to have a map within a map for this to work, but I'm struggling to work out a way forward. I may well be barking up the wrong tree entirely though. I don't really want to manually loop through and add each item one at a time; I'm looking for something more intelligent than that if possible.

```
enum ContentType: String  {
    case Tables,Chairs
}

let original_values: [String:Any]
    =  ["1234":["Tables":"5","Chairs":"2"]]
let values: [Int:[ContentType:Int]]
    = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: original_values.map {
        (
            Int($0.key)!,
            (($0.value as? [String:String]).map { // Error on this line - expects 1 argument but two were used
                (
                    ContentType(rawValue: $1.key)!, // $1 is presumably wrong here?
                    Int($1.value)
                )
            }) as? [ContentType:Int]
        )
    })
```

Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```swift
(($0.value as? [String:String]).map {
```

You using not `Sequence.map`, but `Optional.map`.

Working solution:

```swift
/// First let's map plain types to our types
let resultArray = original_values
    .compactMap { (key, value) -> (Int, [ContentType: Int])? in
        guard let iKey = Int(key), let dValue = value as? [String: String] else { return nil }
        let contentValue = dValue.compactMap { (key, value) -> (ContentType, Int)? in
            guard let cKey = ContentType(rawValue: key), let iValue = Int(value) else { return nil }
            return (cKey, iValue)
        }
        let contentDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: contentValue)
        return (iKey, contentDict)
    }
let result = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: resultArray)
```

To improve print output add conform to `CustomStringConvertible`:

```swift
extension ContentType: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Tables:
            return "Tables"
        case .Chairs:
            return "Chairs"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach, thank you! Unfortunately I'm getting a `[1234: [__lldb_expr_19.ContentType.Chairs: 2, __lldb_expr_19.ContentType.Tables: 5]]` in a playground - whatever that means...

Comment: @Ben, that looks OK to me

Comment: @Ben that is right. Playground compile your code in internal module, so you getting this additional prefixes to enum

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to convert a value I get from an API to a specific format.

You can make your enum `Decodable`

```
enum ContentType: String, Decodable {
    case tables, chairs
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Tables = "Tables"
        case Chairs = "Chairs"
    }
}
```

Then you can decode received `Data` and then `compactMap` it to format `(Int, [ContentType: Int])`. These tuples you can convert to `Dictionary` using designed initializer

```
do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [ContentType: Int]].self, from: data)
    let mapped = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: decoded.compactMap { (key,value) -> (Int, [ContentType: Int])? in
        if let int = Int(key) {
            return (int, value)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    })
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: It's not answer on OP question. But huge plus for Decodable. But why you decode `[String: ...]` instead `[Int: ...]`? Problem with decodable is when at least one integer somewhere inside will be wrong, then whole decode will fail.

Comment: @ManWithBear I decode `[String: ...]` and remap it because keys in dictionary from response are `String` not `Int`. Also for your last sentence: It won't because I use `compactMap`

Comment: in such case you need to decode in `[String: [ContentType: String]]` and then map value inside value as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is Swift 5 correct syntax

```
enum ContentType: String  {
    case tables = "Tables"
    case chairs = "Chairs"
}

let originalValues: [String: [String: String]]
    =  ["1234": ["Tables": "5", "Chairs": "2"]]

    let values: [Int: [ContentType: Int]] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
        originalValues.map { arg in
            let (key, innerDict) = arg
            let outMap: [ContentType: Int] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
                innerDict.map { innerArg in
                let (innerKey, innerValue) = innerArg
                return (ContentType.init(rawValue: innerKey)!, Int(innerValue)!)
            }
            )
            return (Int(key)!, outMap)
        }
    )
    print(values)
```

> [1234: [__lldb_expr_5.ContentType.tables: 5, __lldb_expr_5.ContentType.chairs: 2]]

Comment: You should never use explicitly unwrapped optionals when working with backend data

Comment: This is just a playground example